# Uploading big mp4 video files using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, rest, video, file-upload, upload

I want to upload big mp4 video files (500MB - 1GB) in my angular app using a rest api (and compressed them before if possible). I've tried to use [ng-file-upload](https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/) but it doesn't work with videos bigger than 20Mb.

Please how can I achieve such a task ?

*PS: my server side is written in PHP*

Answer (score 0):

From the description above it sounds that there may be a server restriction on the maximum file size that can be uploaded - this is quite common and the way to set or change the maximum size will depend on the the server. As an example here is some config for AWS S3 storage which shows the min and max file sizes:

```js
   var s3Policy = {
        'expiration': expiration,
        'conditions': [{
                'bucket': aws.bucket
            },
            ['starts-with', '$key', path], 
            {
                'acl': readType
            },
            {
              'success_action_status': '201'
            },
            ['starts-with', '$Content-Type', request.type],
            ['content-length-range', 2048, 124857600], //min and max
        ]
    };
```

If you do just need some example Angular codes for video upload, then the code below is an example of how to upload videos from a web page/app to a server - it is AngularJS 1:

```js
// Controls video upload from web uses module and apraoch at: https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload
app.controller('WebUploadCtrl',[ '$scope', '$upload','colabConfig', function($scope, $upload, colabConfig) {
    console.log("WebUploadCtrl controller");
    $scope.progressPerCent = 0;
    $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
        console.log("file selected for upload...");
        //$files: an array of files selected, each file has name, size, and type.
        for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
          var file = $files[i];
          $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
            url: yourConfig.yourBaseURL + "/web_video_upload",
            method: 'POST',
            //headers: {'header-key': 'header-value'},
            //withCredentials: true,
            data: {myObj: $scope.myModelObj},
            file: file,
          }).progress(function(evt) {
              console.log("progress: " + (evt.position/evt.totalSize)*100);
              //$scope.$apply(function() {
                  $scope.progressPerCent = (evt.position/evt.totalSize)*100;
              //});
          }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // file is uploaded successfully
            console.log(data);
          }).error(function() {
            console.log("Error on web video upload");
          });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing the property in web config file

```
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="30000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```